# Swift:String is not convertible to NSString when I name my project "Foundation"

Tags: string, swift, nsstring

I have tried this :

```
import Foundation
let myString: NSString = "123"
```

I got a error message:`'String' is not convertible to 'NSString'`

I have no idea how to correct this.

Please show me how to correct this error, thank you.

---

Here is about my environment:
OS X 10.10.1
Xcode 6.1.1

I want to post screenshot but I don't have enough reputation.

I tried it again, it was no error message when I used the *playground*, but the same error message came when I complied in *Command Line Tool Project*.

---

Finally I know why I got this error message, My project name was Foundation, was the same as the *Library Foundation*, I created a new project with a new name, there was no more error message~LOL~

Comment: If this is *really all* you were doing, then you would be quoting [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html) verbatim (about one page down), so it should not fail in any case.

Are you sure this is *all* you have been doing and this is exactly the line you get the error on? Maybe you should describe your environment a little more so we can maybe figure out the difference.

Comment: `let myString: NSString = "123"` compiles fine without errors

Comment: Please add your own answer "Finally I know..." as an answer below, and mark that as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know why I got this error message, My project name was Foundation, was the same as the Library Foundation, I created a new project with a new name, there was no more error message~LOL~